# Edge probability of random graph with prescribed degree sequence

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph which is randomly generated from degree sequence D = (d1, d2, .., dn) and x, y are vertices in G. How to compute the probability that (x, y) is an edge of G?

Comment: Consider this question:  If you choose $x$ and $y$ before determining the degree of each vertex, how is that different from choosing the graph first and then choosing $x$ and $y$ at random?

Comment: @Andrew D. King: The approach is good, but very deceptive (or maybe I'm messed somewhere). I take it as you pretend $\frac1{n(n-1)}\sum_{k=1}^n d_n$ to be an answer. But consider this: $D=(2,2,2,2,2,2,2)$. There are two such non-isomorphic graphs: 7-cycle and 4-cycle+triangle. On 7 vertices, there are $6!/2=360$ graphs of the first type and ${7 \choose 3}\times 3 = 84$ of the second. Now  $(x,y)$ is an edge in $5!=120$ 7-cycles and in $20+5\times 3=35$ of the 2nd type. So the probability is $155/444\neq 7/21$ (again, correct me if I miscounted).

Comment: Pardon. Now I see: $7 \choose 3=35$. Still I can't understand fully why it works.

Comment: ${7\choose 3}=35$

Comment: Now I understand: despite $S_n$ is acting differently on non-isomorphic graphs, for each of them the probability is equal. Sorry for putting a lot of self-discussion to the comments.

Comment: I think the question assumes that the degrees are associated with the vertices.

Comment: Sorry for unclear question. Yes, the degrees are associated with vertices, i.e, x and y have fixed degree dx and dy respectively.

Comment: Do you allow loops/multiple edges in the graph, or would thi be sufficient for your purpose?

Answer (score 2):

I want to show, that your problem can be solved by solving $O(n)$ times more common problem:

> Problem 2: What is the number of graphs with degrees $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$?

Let's denote this number by $f(d_1,\dots,d_n)$. It's generating function is equal to
$$F=F(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\prod_{i< j}(1+z_iz_j)\tag{1}$$
(assuming that multiple edges and cycle-edges are not allowed). For simplicity I'll assume, that $x$ is a first vertex (with degree $d_1$) and $y$ is the second and $d_1\leq d_2$. Probability, you are interested in, is equal to
$$p=1-g(d_1,\dots,d_n)/f(d_1,\dots,d_n)\tag{2},$$
where $g(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ is equal to number of graphs with degrees $(d_1,\dots,d_n)$ which does not contain edge $\{1,2\}$. It's generating function is equal to $$G=G(z_1,\dots,z_n)=\prod_{i< j;\{i,j\}\neq\{1,2\}}(1+z_iz_j),\tag{3}$$
so we have
$$F=(1+z_1z_2)G.\tag{4}$$
Therefore
$$f(d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots,d_n)=g(d_1,d_2,d_3,\dots,d_n)+g(d_1-1,d_2-1,d_3,\dots,d_n)\tag{5}$$ and
$$g(d_1,\dots,d_n)=\sum_{k=0}^{d_1} (-1)^k f(d_1-k,d_2-k,d_3,\dots,d_n).\tag{6}$$
From (2) and (6) we see, that solving problem 2 ($d_1+1$ times) is enough for calculating desired probability.

Of course problem 2 can be solved in time $c(n(n-1)/2)(d_1+1)(d_2+1)\dots (d_n+1)$, but I think you can try to find a better solution. Problem 2 might be a known graph enumeration problem. Probably you already know about [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=o9WecWgilzYC&dq=labelled+graph+enumeration+degree+fixed&lr=&source=gbs_navlinks_s), but if you don't, take a look.

Comment: Thanks Fiktor. However, in the paper named Analysis of weighted networks, Newman claimed that probability equals to $(d_i\times d_j)/\sum_k d_k$, but I do not understand why

Comment: Assume the graph with 102 vertices with $d_i=101$, $d_j=101$ and $d_k=2$ for $k\neq i$, $k\neq j$. Then the "probability", written in your comment is equal to $10201/402$ (greater than 1). However it is equal to 1, because there is only one graph with a degree sequence, described above.

Comment: Thanks Fiktor. I asked prof. Newman and he answered that's only a approximation of desired probability. Here are some more information about this model and other similar models http://benjamingood.wordpress.com/2010/01/18/clearing-up-the-configuration-model/
Now I know that a nice explicit formula to compute this probability does not exist.
One more time, thank you for your help.